# How to lock Data Validation Cells and unlock on double clicking

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to lock all the cells in my sheet and unlock them for editing by double clicking and entering a password.

My only problem is the code is not at all working for Data Validation cells. Theres no way i can double click and edit data validation values.

Also is there a way i can have blank cells automatically unprotected and get protected once a value is entered and then double clicking to request password to unlock the cell just like the code im using.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel 
    As Boolean)
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
    changeInput = MsgBox("Do you want to unlock the sheet?", vbYesNo + 
    vbQuestion, "Unlock sheet")
    If changeInput = vbYes Then
        Dim pass As String
        pass = InputBox("Enter Password")
            If pass <> "password" Then
                MsgBox ("Wrong password")
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
                Target.Locked = False
            End If
    End If
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    For Each cel In Target
    If cel.Value <> "" Then
        cel.Locked = True
    End If
    Next cel
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

    End Sub
```

The code works on all other cells but i was hoping blank cells would be editable and this code doesnt work on data validation cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Data-Validation cells try, in your worksheet_change event:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Password:="password"
```

instead of

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
```

a way to have blank cells automatically unprotected is to make sure all blank cells are not locked from scratch.

Comment: Thank you as some of your suggestions worked. But still im not able to double click data validation cells and input the password before getting access to edit.

Comment: You did first Unprotect the sheet, ((Review Tab, Unprotect Sheet)?

Comment: Yes, all that worked.Only part is im still not able to double click data validation cells and edit.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hhbs_CwGZ2XqbqLVp36tg3R85aMYxq-t9f8RoMKRz3k/edit?usp=sharing